# What was Avilio's alibi during the after-credits scene in episode 2?

Tags: crunchyroll, 91-days

In the after-credits scene of episode 2 of *91 Days*, Nero questions Avilio about the circumstances of Vanno's death. Crunchyroll translates the dialogue as follows:

> AVILIO: He stole Vanno's gun. I shot Serpente, but it was too late.
>
> BARBERO: Your hands weren't tied?
>
> AVILIO: Serpente said he'd let me pray. Then he tied up Vanno...

Is that actually his alibi? It doesn't make a whole lot of sense that Serpente would have to steal Vanno's gun if Avilio were already tied up. And why would Serpente let Avilio pray *and then* tie up Vanno? This doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Answer (score 5):

No! This is an egregious case of getting your implied referents mixed up. The Japanese dialogue is:

> AVILIO: ヴァンノが銃を奪われて…俺がセルペンテを撃ったが、遅かった。
>
> BARBERO: 縄をかけなかったのか。
>
> AVILIO: 祈らせてくれと、セルペンテが。それでヴァンノは縄を…

Here's what this actually means:

> AVILIO: He stole Vanno's gun. I shot Serpente, but it was too late.
>
> BARBERO: **You didn't tie his hands?**
>
> AVILIO: **Serpente asked us to let him pray. Then Vanno untied his hands...**

This obviously makes a whole lot more sense. Avilio's alibi starts out the same as what actually happened - Vanno captures Serpente during the assassination attempt on Fango. But Avilio then claims that rather than begging to be spared, Serpente actually asks Vanno to let him pray. When Vanno unties Serpente's hands, Serpente presumably wrestles for Vanno's gun and shoots him before Avilio brings Serpente down.